# Does highcharts support displaying groups of columns at different x values?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am essentially trying to display multiple charts at the same time for different categories/x values. Each x value is a category that has a variable number of columns that I want to display. I get pretty close like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6ma07nhw/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['group 0', 'groub 1', 'group 2', 'group 3', 'group 4', 'group 5', 'group 6']
  },

  series: [
                {data: [{x: 0,y: 10}, {x: 1,y: 20}, {x: 5,y: 15}, {x: 2,y: 10}, {x: 3,y: 40}, {x: 6,y: 20}]},
          {data: [{x: 1,y: 10},  {x: 5,y: 10} ]},
      {data: [{x: 1,y: 19}]},
      {data: [{x: 1,y: 10}]},
  ]

});
```

Each series only has one value per x. For each distinct column at an x I've created a new series. Visually this is close (except the series are not related so I'd need to modify the hover and change/hide the legend). But the columns are off center. If I add more series this becomes more and more noticeable. I guess its space for each series.

It seems like using multiple series is intended to display values once per x value per series. When I try to render it all in one series the columns overlap each other: https://jsfiddle.net/ko2vpbsg/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['group 0', 'groub 1', 'group 2', 'group 3', 'group 4', 'group 5', 'group 6']
  },

  series: [{ 
      data: [{x: 0,y: 10}, {x: 1,y: 20}, {x: 1,y: 10}, {x: 5,y: 15}, {x: 2,y: 10}, {x: 5,y: 10}, {x: 3,y: 40}, {x: 1,y: 19}, {x: 1,y: 10}, {x: 6,y: 20}]
  }]

});
```

Does highcharts support rendering a column chart in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use the first approach with multiple series. You can apply the same options for many series by using `plotOptions` property. Enable `centerInCategory` to ignore null or missing points.

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            centerInCategory: true
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b4gdjtz7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.centerInCategory